# How to unfollow deleted site SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, site, following

[image]

Here is my problem at SharePoint. That site is deleted but still on my followed sites.

Comment: When you deleted the site, how many days before?

Answer (score 0):

All contents of the site will also be temporarily retained. You can delete a site completely in two ways:

1.Go to Deleted sites in the SharePoint admin center, and sign in with an account that has admin permissions for your organization.Select Delete->confirm->Delete.（Effective time may be longer）

2.Use the following SharePoint Online Management Shell code:

```
Remove-SPODeletedSite -Identity https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/sitetoremove
```

For more details, please refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/delete-site-collection

After my test, there is no way to take effect immediately, maybe you can try to wait a little longer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of known issue in SharePoint online. When you delete a SharePoint site, it still shows in Following and Frequent Sites section. Maybe because of this:

> Deleted SharePoint sites are retained for 93 days. After 93 days, sites and all their content and settings are permanently deleted, including lists, libraries, pages, and any subsites.

**Source**: [Restore deleted sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/restore-deleted-site-collection).

---

You can try below and see if it works for you:

1. Try unfollowing the site manually from SharePoint home page.
2. Ensure deleted sites are removed. If you are a SharePoint tenant admin, please try removing the deleted site via [Remove-SPODeletedSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/remove-spodeletedsite) command manually.
3. After you manually delete the deleted sites, please wait for 30 days and check if the situation remains.

---

Check below similar threads for more information related to this:

1. [SharePoint Online deleted site still showing on home page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-online-deleted-site-still-showing-on/a5f2c477-2b7d-4033-836f-7c0ea5756fa3)
2. [Deleted sites not disappearing from frequent sites](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/deleted-sites-not-disappearing-from-frequent-sites/m-p/179575)
3. [SharePoint online frequent sites](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-online-frequent-sites/2ef13544-f260-484c-b4b6-22230393de99)
4. [Deleted Sites Still showing in Favorites](https://www.reddit.com/r/sharepoint/comments/mlb8pg/deleted_sites_still_showing_in_favorites/)

---

You can also vote on related feedbacks/ideas posted on SharePoint feedback portal:

1. [Clear deleted SharePoint groups from Frequent Sites and Suggested Sites](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/3f0a5faf-dd1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8914)
2. [Remove deleted sites from SharePoint Home](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/1c0973d4-dd1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8914)

Comment: This is unrelated to deleted sites still being in 1st or 2nd stage recycle bins.

Answer (score 0):

The question here is how can a user interact with SharePoint in order to unfollow a site that has been deleted. I noticed sites that have been long gone from the recycle bins (over 2 years since they have been deleted) that are still being shown in the list of followed sites for a few users. So this has nothing to do with PowerShell commands for deleting a site, or removing it from the recycle bin.

If you actually Click on the SharePoint logo at the top-left bar (next to the app launcher logo), it will show you a page that lists your Frequent Sites and Suggested sites. And on the left-hand side, there will be a menu showing your frequent sites with the clickable start icon next to them. I managed to unfollow deleted sites from this page.

[image]

However, it seems that even after unfollowing those sites, they are still listed under the Globe icon for the user, like this:

[image]

This is poor coding from Microsoft, pure and simple.